# Add controls and event handlers dynamically C#

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, panel

I have tried to dynamically add panels and their event handlers using the code below.

However it does not seem to work (trigger the event when clicked) although it is similar to many of the available answers.

Please help if possible.

```
int items = 0;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

    foreach (KnownColor knowColor in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)))
    {
        Color color = Color.FromKnownColor(knowColor);
        al.Add(color.Name);
    }

    foreach (string i in al)
    {
        addListItem(i);
    }
}

public void addListItem(string item)
{
    Panel pnlItem = new Panel();

    pnlItem.Location = new Point(0, items * 25);
    pnlItem.Name = "pnl" + item;
    pnlItem.Size = new Size(250, 25);
    pnlList.Controls.Add(pnlItem);

    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = item;
    pnlItem.Controls.Add(lbl);

    pnlItem.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(pnlItem_MouseClick);

    items++;
}

void pnlItem_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("panel was clicked");
}
```

Comment: No. That's fine. They can be contained inside other controls.

Comment: so how do i get this to work, because everything looks fine, but it doesn't trigger the event..

Comment: Are you clicking on the panel itself or the label inside the panel?

Comment: you added the event only on item's mouseclick, you should be adding the mouseclick event handler even to the label

Comment: If you will add the following lines to your code you'll see how LarsTech's answer fixes your code:

`pnlItem.BackColor = Color.Blue;`

and:

`lbl.BackColor = Color.Red;`

And click on the blue area.

Comment: thanks ispiro, this helped identify the problem, i was clicking the lable all the time because the container panel was too small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are clicking on the label.  Add that handler, too:

```
pnlItem.MouseClick += pnlItem_MouseClick;
lbl.MouseClick += pnlItem_MouseClick;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you're either clicking the label or no part of the panel at all.  I tried the code, it works, but do what the others have said and add a back color so you know where to click.  Be aware the areas around the label may also register as the "label" even though it seems as though you are clicking on the panel itself, (the area directly below it especially).